# Poisson Distribution to determine number of defective tyres.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

In a certain factory producing cycle tyres, there is a small chance of 1 in 500 tyres to be defective.  The  tyres  are  supplied  in  lots  of  10.  Using  Poisson  distribution, calculate the approximate number of lots containing no defective tyres in a consignment of 10,000 lots.

First we have to calculate $\lambda$ which is equal to $np$. My confusion is what should be the criteria for choosing $n$ ? In this case I have to select $n=$ 10,000 or 10 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of defectives in a lot of $10$ has mean $10/500$. It is binomially distributed, but since $10/500$ is small, the probability a lot  has no defectives is well-approximated by the probability that a Poisson with parameter $\lambda=10/500$ takes on the value $0$.

Thus the probability $p$ of no defectives in a lot of $10$ is given approximately by $p=e^{-10/500}$.

We interpret approximate number of lots with no defectives as the **mean** number of lots with no defective. This is $10000p$.

*Remark:* We dragged in the Poisson only because the problem seems to ask us to do so. However, finding the mean number of defective lots in $10000$ does not require the Poisson, and the Poisson approximation does not even simplify the computation.

Comment: This actually works better than I expected, since $e^{-10/500}$ is closer to $(499/500)^{10}$ than I thought.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be clearer, if a bit longer, to write out in some detail about what you're approximating with what. That's because there are really two $n$s and two $p$s in the model, but you're only going to use one of each in your Poisson approximation.

First, we have the probability distribution for the number of defective tires in a given lot of 10. This is a binomial random variable with $n=10,p=(1/500)$. The probability that this is zero is the probability that a given lot of tires has no defective tires in it. This is exactly $(499/500)^{10}$.

Next, we have the probability distribution for the number of lots in a consignment of 10000 lots which contain no defective tires. Now the probability of a lot to have no defective tires is $(499/500)^{10}$ (we already computed it), so this is a binomial random variable with $n=10000$ and $p=(499/500)^{10}$.

Now you approximate *that* binomial variable with a Poisson variable with *those* values of $n$ and $p$.

Comment: The probability that a given lot of tires has no defective tires in it. This is exactly $(\frac{1}{500})^{10}$ , it should be $(\frac{499}{500})^{10}$, right ?

Comment: @MojoJojo Yes, I fixed that earlier.

Comment: @Ian: The probability of no defective in a lot is about $0.98$. For the Poisson approximation, presumably we use the probability of at least one defective, roughly $0.02$. Still, multiplied by $10000$ this gives rather large $\lambda$, the normal approximation to the binomial may be more suitable at this level.

Comment: @AndréNicolas If $p$ is small and $np$ is large, the normal approximation and Poisson approximation to the binomial will be essentially the same, because the Poisson itself will be well-approximated by a normal with just a slightly larger variance ($np$ vs. $np-np^2$). I think this occurs in this context. In any case you are right that "the approximate number of lots with no defectives" will be close to the average i.e. around $10000(499/500)^{10} \approx 9802$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas In fact here we needn't even have as much context as we do: except for variables with huge or infinite variance, this $n$ is big enough for the law of large numbers alone.